# Issues accessing kinesis from EC2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I have some java code that pulls records from **Kinesis**. It runs fine on my laptop (regardless of IP) but when I attempt to run it on EC2 I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
  at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1119)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:759)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:723)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
  at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1271)
  at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1247)
  at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:454)
at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:431)
```

The code in question that seems to be making it unhappy:

```
AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient sts = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient();

AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = sts.assumeRole(new AssumeRoleRequest()
            .withRoleArn(config.getString("kinesis/arn"))
            .withExternalId(config.getString("kinesis/external_id"))
            .withRoleSessionName(config.getString("kinesis/role_session_name")));
```

Im wondering if this has something to do with how the EC2 instance was built. But the fact that it runs fine from my debugger has me confused.

Ive checked to make sure the various config values are coming through correctly.

---

Per @prayagupd Ive updated the EC2 instance to include this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kinesis:Get*",
        "kinesis:List*",
        "kinesis:Describe*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: 
User: arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/kinesis-consumer/i-cab01a5 
is not authorized to perform: 
sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::12345:role/kinesis-consumer
```

Comment: AWS by default looks for credentials in the order (credential chain) listed here, are you sure you have credentials setup as described here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html? What is config object and how you are creating it?

Answer (score 1):

From your ec2 you need to authenticate through your [ec2 VM Profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).

I use the following code which connects to kinesis with property `AwsProfileNameLoader.AWS_PROFILE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY` in local which uses `(~/.aws/credentials)`, for me `~/.aws/credentials` is temporary.

So I use `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` inside ec2 which actually looks for ec2 instance profile.

You still can put your credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` and use the same.

```
/**
 * provides credentials for a client to make connection to the elastic cloud instance
 *
 * @return DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
 */
private DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain getAuthProfileCredentials() {
    if (myAppConfig.getProperty("authentication.profile") != null) {
        System.setProperty(AwsProfileNameLoader.AWS_PROFILE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, myAppConfig.getProperty("authentication.profile"));
    }
    return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
}
```

Your ec2 instance profile needs to have [kinesis access IAM role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#kinesis-using-iam-examples) with following trust-relationship.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: trust-relationship]

And role-policy should have

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:*:stream/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Then kinesis access can be verified with following commands on ec2 machine (`aws` cli should have been installed)

```
aws kinesis create-stream --stream-name gregor-samsa-ping --shard-count 1 --region us-west-2

aws kinesis list-streams --region us-west-2
{
    "StreamNames": [
        "gregor-samsa-ping"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Im still confused as to why my code would run on a development laptop but not on EC2.

Comment: are you using `~/.aws/credentials` in local and is the token something that expires?

Comment: The credentials in question are not mine - they were furnished by the owner of the Kinesis instance. Why would they work in an IDE but not EC2?

Comment: Saw your updated answer, now seems your Role assigned to ec2 instance is somehow not working but at least skipped looking for `~/.aws/credentials`. For reference see the example I had for [stream connection from ec2](https://github.com/duwamish-os/elasticC2-kinesis-connection/blob/master/StreamingConsumerVM.json#L58). Also can you check you this [`assumedRolePolicy`](https://github.com/duwamish-os/elasticC2-kinesis-connection/blob/master/StreamingConsumerVM.json#L111) on the role?

Comment: @ethrbunny Wait a min. if your ec2 machine is Amazon Linux, can you check `aws kinesis list-streams`? (Amazon linux has aws cli installed i believe), it will fail if you don't have proper Role assigned to that ec2 machine. So, if you fix that then your code should work as well.

Comment: Do you have streams at all? Try creating one from ec2 machine itself  `aws kinesis create-stream --stream-name gregor-samsa-deleteme --shard-count 1` and then `aws kinesis list`. If that works issue is with Java API.